# How to change the timezone setting of Windows2k8 with .net

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, pinvoke

I have tried to change the timezone of my system with c# code for a few days now and nothing I'm trying is making much sense or working at all.  I started out trying to use the PInvoke syntax for SetTimeZoneInformation that I've seen on other questions here.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] private static extern bool
SetTimeZoneInformation([In] ref TimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);
```

I was looking into how I should create the TimeZoneInformation struct and got confused since my system obviously has a dynamic DST system.  Turns out that ever since Vista Microsoft added a new way of handling Timezones.  You now have to use SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation([In] ref DynamicTimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);
```

I searched for help with this API on msdn and found something saying, "An application must have the SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME privilege for this function to succeed."  Eventually I found [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3962474.php) page with what seems like pretty good code for getting this done.  The problem is that it's just not working.

Here is my non-working code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LUID
{
    public int LowPart;
    public int HighPart;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
{
    public LUID Luid;
    public UInt32 Attributes;
    public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SystemTime
{
    public ushort Year;
    public ushort Month;
    public ushort DayOfWeek;
    public ushort Day;
    public ushort Hour;
    public ushort Minute;
    public ushort Second;
    public ushort Millisecond;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct DynamicTimeZoneInformation
{
    public int bias;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string standardName;
    public SystemTime standardDate;
    public int standardBias;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string daylightName;
    public SystemTime daylightDate;
    public int daylightBias;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string timeZoneKeyName;
    public bool dynamicDaylightTimeDisabled;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(out DynamicTimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation([In] ref DynamicTimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int OpenProcessToken(int ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, ref int tokenhandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetCurrentProcess();

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpsystemname, string lpname, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int AdjustTokenPrivileges(int tokenhandle, int disableprivs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES Newstate, int bufferlength, int PreivousState, int Returnlength);

public const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x00000001;
public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x00000002;
public const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x00000004;
public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
public const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x00000010;
public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x00000040;
public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x00000080;

public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT = 0x00000001;
public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED = 0x00000004;
public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS = 0x80000000;

public static bool EnablePrivilege(string privilege)
{
    try
    {
        int token = 0;
        int retVal = 0;

        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
        LUID LD = new LUID();

        retVal = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
        retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref LD);


        TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        TP.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        TP.Luid = LD;

        retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static bool DisablePrivilege(string privilege)
{
    try
    {
        int token = 0;
        int retVal = 0;

        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
        LUID LD = new LUID();

        retVal = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
        retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref LD);
        TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        // TP.Attributes should be none (not set) to disable privilege
        TP.Luid = LD;

        retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public bool SetSystemTimeZone(string timeZoneId)
{
    //I'm using the TimeZoneInfo class to populate a list in the UI.  This code to retrieve the correct timezone is working
    TimeZoneInfo newTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    DynamicTimeZoneInformation dtzi = new DynamicTimeZoneInformation();
    dtzi.bias = -(Convert.ToInt32(newTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes));
    dtzi.standardBias = 0;
    //Here's where I start to lose it.  I don't know which adjustment rule to use from the GetAdjustmentRules call.  I'm just using the last one as that seems to usually be the most recent, but it doesn't always have to be.
    dtzi.daylightBias = Convert.ToInt32(newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightDelta.TotalMinutes);
    dtzi.standardName = newTimeZone.StandardName;
    dtzi.daylightName = newTimeZone.DaylightName;
    //It would be nice if this key name would just look up the timezone from the registry and use its settings
    dtzi.timeZoneKeyName = newTimeZone.Id;

    //No idea if this is the right way to create the SystemTime object I need here.
    SystemTime standardDate = new SystemTime();
    standardDate.Year = 0;
    standardDate.Hour = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionEnd.TimeOfDay.Hour;
    standardDate.Minute = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionEnd.TimeOfDay.Minute;
    standardDate.DayOfWeek = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionEnd.DayOfWeek;
    standardDate.Month = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionEnd.Month;
    standardDate.Day = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionEnd.Week;
    dtzi.standardDate = standardDate;

    SystemTime daylightDate = new SystemTime();
    standardDate.Year = 0;
    standardDate.Hour = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionStart.TimeOfDay.Hour;
    standardDate.Minute = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionStart.TimeOfDay.Minute;
    standardDate.DayOfWeek = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionStart.DayOfWeek;
    standardDate.Month = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionStart.Month;
    standardDate.Day = (ushort)newTimeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().Last().DaylightTransitionStart.Week;
    dtzi.daylightDate = daylightDate;

    dtzi.dynamicDaylightTimeDisabled = false;


    EnablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");
    if (!SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(ref dtzi))
        returnVal = false;
    DisablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");

    return returnVal;
}
```

Has anyone had any luck with this...setting the timezone in a post Vista system?  Perhaps there is a better way altogether.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've done this before and here's how I did it.

<strike>The only problem is that when you check the DateTime in the task bar, it says `Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone using the link below.`. I've never been able to "fix" that... so yeah.</strike>

**EDIT**: I found a way to make the timezone "valid" (you must restart the machine to make it work). Be sure to read the NOTE that explains that `app.manifest` needs `requireAdministrator`. ^_^

Good luck!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace TimeZoneTest
{

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SystemTime
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Year;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Month;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short DayOfWeek;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Day;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Hour;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Minute;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Second;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Milliseconds;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct TimeZoneInformation
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int Bias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        public string StandardName;
        public SystemTime StandardDate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int StandardBias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        public string DaylightName;
        public SystemTime DaylightDate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int DaylightBias;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RegistryTimeZoneInformation
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int Bias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int StandardBias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int DaylightBias;
        public SystemTime StandardDate;
        public SystemTime DaylightDate;

        public RegistryTimeZoneInformation(TimeZoneInformation tzi)
        {
            this.Bias = tzi.Bias;
            this.StandardDate = tzi.StandardDate;
            this.StandardBias = tzi.StandardBias;
            this.DaylightDate = tzi.DaylightDate;
            this.DaylightBias = tzi.DaylightBias;
        }

        public RegistryTimeZoneInformation(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if ((bytes == null) || (bytes.Length != 0x2c))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument_InvalidREG_TZI_FORMAT");
            }
            this.Bias = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
            this.StandardBias = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
            this.DaylightBias = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 8);
            this.StandardDate.Year = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 12);
            this.StandardDate.Month = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 14);
            this.StandardDate.DayOfWeek = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x10);
            this.StandardDate.Day = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x12);
            this.StandardDate.Hour = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 20);
            this.StandardDate.Minute = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x16);
            this.StandardDate.Second = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x18);
            this.StandardDate.Milliseconds = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x1a);
            this.DaylightDate.Year = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x1c);
            this.DaylightDate.Month = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 30);
            this.DaylightDate.DayOfWeek = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x20);
            this.DaylightDate.Day = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x22);
            this.DaylightDate.Hour = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x24);
            this.DaylightDate.Minute = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x26);
            this.DaylightDate.Second = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 40);
            this.DaylightDate.Milliseconds = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x2a);
        }
    }

    public class TokenPrivilegesAccess
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int OpenProcessToken(int ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess,
        ref int tokenhandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpsystemname, string lpname,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int AdjustTokenPrivileges(int tokenhandle, int disableprivs,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGE Newstate, int bufferlength,
            int PreivousState, int Returnlength);

        public const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x00000001;
        public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x00000002;
        public const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x00000004;
        public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
        public const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x00000010;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x00000040;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x00000080;

        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT = 0x00000001;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED = 0x00000004;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS = 0x80000000;

        public static bool EnablePrivilege(string privilege)
        {
            try
            {
                int token = 0;
                int retVal = 0;

                TOKEN_PRIVILEGE TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGE();
                LUID LD = new LUID();

                retVal = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
                retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref LD);
                TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;

                var luidAndAtt = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES();
                luidAndAtt.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
                luidAndAtt.Luid = LD;
                TP.Privilege = luidAndAtt;

                retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool DisablePrivilege(string privilege)
        {
            try
            {
                int token = 0;
                int retVal = 0;

                TOKEN_PRIVILEGE TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGE();
                LUID LD = new LUID();

                retVal = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
                retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref LD);
                TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;
                // TP.Attributes should be none (not set) to disable privilege
                var luidAndAtt = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES();
                luidAndAtt.Luid = LD;
                TP.Privilege = luidAndAtt;

                retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        internal uint LowPart;
        internal uint HighPart;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        internal LUID Luid;
        internal uint Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGE
    {
        internal uint PrivilegeCount;
        internal LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privilege;
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 0x005;
        public const int CORSEC_E_MISSING_STRONGNAME = -2146233317;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SetTimeZoneInformation([In] ref TimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var regTimeZones = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones");

            // Print out all the possible time-zones.
            //foreach(var subKey in regTimeZones.GetSubKeyNames())
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(subKey);
            //}

            var subKey = regTimeZones.GetSubKeyNames().Where(s => s == "Atlantic Standard Time").First();
            string daylightName = (string)regTimeZones.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("Dlt");
            string standardName = (string)regTimeZones.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("Std");
            byte[] tzi = (byte[])regTimeZones.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("TZI");

            var regTzi = new RegistryTimeZoneInformation(tzi);

            var tz = new TimeZoneInformation();
            tz.Bias = regTzi.Bias;
            tz.DaylightBias = regTzi.DaylightBias;
            tz.StandardBias = regTzi.StandardBias;
            tz.DaylightDate = regTzi.DaylightDate;
            tz.StandardDate = regTzi.StandardDate;
            tz.DaylightName = daylightName;
            tz.StandardName = standardName;

            TokenPrivilegesAccess.EnablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");
            bool didSet = Program.SetTimeZoneInformation(ref tz);
            int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            TokenPrivilegesAccess.DisablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");

            // NOTE: This fixes the "Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone using the link below" error 
            //       only when the machine is *restarted*.
            //       
            //       You must have the following set in your app.manifest to request admin rights to write to this key.
            //       <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
            //          <security>
            //          <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
            //              <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
            //          </requestedPrivileges>
            //      ...
            var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\TimeZoneInformation", true);
            key.SetValue("TimeZoneKeyName", key.GetValue("StandardName"));

            if (didSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success, TimeZone Set!");
            }
            else
            {

                if (lastError == Program.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Access denied... Try running application as administrator.");
                }
                else if (lastError == Program.CORSEC_E_MISSING_STRONGNAME)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Application is not signed ... Right click the project > Signing > Check 'Sign the assembly'.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32Error: " + lastError + "\nHRESULT: " + Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying various code snippets from across the internet and SO, but this is the first one to work.  THANKS!

Comment: Note, this answer doesn't use `SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`, and thus is not appropriate for Windows Vista and higher.  See Claudio's answer below.

Answer (score 17):

TheCloudlessSky's answer works for windows XP: starting with Vista the function to call is [SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), otherwise "*Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone using the link below.*" will be shown until the next reboot.

Bonus: calling SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation makes it unnecessary to manually edit the registry, and so it won't be necessary to start the program as administrator.

Here is TheCloudlessSky's snippet modified to work on Vista and higher

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace TimeZoneTest
{

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SystemTime
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Year;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Month;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short DayOfWeek;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Day;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Hour;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Minute;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Second;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public short Milliseconds;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct TimeZoneInformation
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int Bias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        public string StandardName;
        public SystemTime StandardDate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int StandardBias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        public string DaylightName;
        public SystemTime DaylightDate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int DaylightBias;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct DynamicTimeZoneInformation
    {
        public int Bias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string StandardName;
        public SystemTime StandardDate;
        public int StandardBias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DaylightName;
        public SystemTime DaylightDate;
        public int DaylightBias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string TimeZoneKeyName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public bool DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RegistryTimeZoneInformation
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int Bias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int StandardBias;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int DaylightBias;
        public SystemTime StandardDate;
        public SystemTime DaylightDate;

        public RegistryTimeZoneInformation(TimeZoneInformation tzi)
        {
            this.Bias = tzi.Bias;
            this.StandardDate = tzi.StandardDate;
            this.StandardBias = tzi.StandardBias;
            this.DaylightDate = tzi.DaylightDate;
            this.DaylightBias = tzi.DaylightBias;
        }

        public RegistryTimeZoneInformation(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if ((bytes == null) || (bytes.Length != 0x2c))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument_InvalidREG_TZI_FORMAT");
            }
            this.Bias = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
            this.StandardBias = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
            this.DaylightBias = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 8);
            this.StandardDate.Year = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 12);
            this.StandardDate.Month = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 14);
            this.StandardDate.DayOfWeek = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x10);
            this.StandardDate.Day = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x12);
            this.StandardDate.Hour = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 20);
            this.StandardDate.Minute = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x16);
            this.StandardDate.Second = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x18);
            this.StandardDate.Milliseconds = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x1a);
            this.DaylightDate.Year = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x1c);
            this.DaylightDate.Month = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 30);
            this.DaylightDate.DayOfWeek = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x20);
            this.DaylightDate.Day = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x22);
            this.DaylightDate.Hour = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x24);
            this.DaylightDate.Minute = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x26);
            this.DaylightDate.Second = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 40);
            this.DaylightDate.Milliseconds = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0x2a);
        }
    }

    public class TokenPrivilegesAccess
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int OpenProcessToken(int ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess,
        ref int tokenhandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpsystemname, string lpname,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int AdjustTokenPrivileges(int tokenhandle, int disableprivs,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGE Newstate, int bufferlength,
            int PreivousState, int Returnlength);

        public const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x00000001;
        public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x00000002;
        public const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x00000004;
        public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
        public const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x00000010;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x00000040;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x00000080;

        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT = 0x00000001;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED = 0x00000004;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS = 0x80000000;

        public static bool EnablePrivilege(string privilege)
        {
            try
            {
                int token = 0;
                int retVal = 0;

                TOKEN_PRIVILEGE TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGE();
                LUID LD = new LUID();

                retVal = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
                retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref LD);
                TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;

                var luidAndAtt = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES();
                luidAndAtt.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
                luidAndAtt.Luid = LD;
                TP.Privilege = luidAndAtt;

                retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool DisablePrivilege(string privilege)
        {
            try
            {
                int token = 0;
                int retVal = 0;

                TOKEN_PRIVILEGE TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGE();
                LUID LD = new LUID();

                retVal = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
                retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref LD);
                TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;
                // TP.Attributes should be none (not set) to disable privilege
                var luidAndAtt = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES();
                luidAndAtt.Luid = LD;
                TP.Privilege = luidAndAtt;

                retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        internal uint LowPart;
        internal uint HighPart;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        internal LUID Luid;
        internal uint Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGE
    {
        internal uint PrivilegeCount;
        internal LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privilege;
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 0x005;
        public const int CORSEC_E_MISSING_STRONGNAME = -2146233317;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SetTimeZoneInformation([In] ref TimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);      

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation([In] ref DynamicTimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var regTimeZones = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones");

            // Print out all the possible time-zones.
            //foreach(var subKey in regTimeZones.GetSubKeyNames())
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(subKey);
            //}

            var subKey = regTimeZones.GetSubKeyNames().Where(s => s == "Atlantic Standard Time").First();
            string daylightName = (string)regTimeZones.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("Dlt");
            string standardName = (string)regTimeZones.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("Std");
            byte[] tzi = (byte[])regTimeZones.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("TZI");

            var regTzi = new RegistryTimeZoneInformation(tzi);

            TokenPrivilegesAccess.EnablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");

            bool didSet;
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            {
                var tz = new TimeZoneInformation();
                tz.Bias = regTzi.Bias;
                tz.DaylightBias = regTzi.DaylightBias;
                tz.StandardBias = regTzi.StandardBias;
                tz.DaylightDate = regTzi.DaylightDate;
                tz.StandardDate = regTzi.StandardDate;
                tz.DaylightName = daylightName;
                tz.StandardName = standardName;

                didSet = Program.SetTimeZoneInformation(ref tz);
            }
            else
            {
                var tz = new DynamicTimeZoneInformation();
                tz.Bias = regTzi.Bias;
                tz.DaylightBias = regTzi.DaylightBias;
                tz.StandardBias = regTzi.StandardBias;
                tz.DaylightDate = regTzi.DaylightDate;
                tz.StandardDate = regTzi.StandardDate;
                tz.DaylightName = daylightName;
                tz.StandardName = standardName;
                tz.TimeZoneKeyName = subKey;
                tz.DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled = false;

                didSet = Program.SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(ref tz);
            }
            int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            TokenPrivilegesAccess.DisablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");

            if (didSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success, TimeZone Set!");
            }
            else
            {

                if (lastError == Program.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Access denied... Try running application as administrator.");
                }
                else if (lastError == Program.CORSEC_E_MISSING_STRONGNAME)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Application is not signed ... Right click the project > Signing > Check 'Sign the assembly'.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32Error: " + lastError + "\nHRESULT: " + Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the marked answer.

Comment: In production, worth noting that you should ensure the privilege is revoked via a `finally` block just to avoid any escalation vulnerability should there be unexpected exceptions.