# want to change the System time zone on selection of time zone from drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change the System time Zone on changing the time Zone selected by user in my Application.

```
 DropDownList2.DataSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
 DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808736/set-system-time-zone-from-net).  Hope this helps.

Comment: i place a label where current time shows.there is another drop down list where all the system time zone shows. i want that the time on label changes automatically to corresponds time zone. how is it possible?

Comment: Are you having winform application or a asp.net website?

Comment: Its in Web site. Actually i want to make further a module in DNN That Contains the Time zone Functionality.

Comment: Does changing the value in dropdown sends the postback?

Comment: Have a look at http://staceyw1.wordpress.com/2006/08/31/convert-local-time-to-timezone/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx