# Change system timezone with Pytz

Tags: windows, timezone, pytz

I have a Timezone in the following format: country/city (for example: America/Sao_Paulo).
I want to change with python my system's timezone (Win7) with it, is it possible to do it with Pytz and Datetime, or at all ?

Thank you !

Comment: On Unix, `os.environ['TZ'] =  'America/Sao_Paulo'; time.tzset()` changes time/datetime local time for your process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. There is not a direct Python way to do this.

It *could* be done, but you would have to jump through a lot of hoops:

- Use [CLDR data](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html) to translate the IANA zone to a Windows zone id.

  - Ex. `America/Sao_Paulo` => `E. South America Standard Time`
  - (See the Databases section of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more details.)
- Get the appropriate Win32 security permissions.
- Call into the Win32 `SetTimeZone` API

Caling Win32 functions from Python is done via [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

[Here's a walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808736/set-system-time-zone-from-net) of which Win32 permissions and calls to make, although it's in C# in this sample.  You will need to translate for Python.

Sounds like a lot of work to me.  Not sure why you would want to do this.