# TimeZoneInfo in different language on RDP

Tags: c#, timezone, rdp

In the source code of our app we have got following line:

`pcTimezone = System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id;`

When I work locally on my office PC (Windows 10 in English, regional settings: English (USA)) everything is fine and `pcTimezone` is set to `"Central European Standard Time"`, but when I am connected from home by RDP `System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` returns

> "Środkowoeuropejski Czas stand"

which is in Polish.

This leads to error

> Time zone ID "Środkowoeuropejski Czas stand" was not found on the local computer

on line `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(pcTimezone)`

I tried setting everything what I could to English on my home computer (system language is unchangeable so it is Polish still) and it did not help.

Is there any way to force value of `System.TimeZoneInfo.Local`?
Or maybe you are able to set RDP not to override it from outer computer?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808736/set-system-time-zone-from-net

Comment: @sr28 - that is unrelated

Comment: Somewhere it is clearly using the `StandardName` property instead of `Id`.  The `Id` is never supposed to be localized.  Are you sure you are using `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` and not `TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName`?

Comment: You might also look to see if [time zone redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc725887.aspx) is enabled.  It should be off by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that for a some strange reason, when connected via RDP, a Time zone of the office PC got set to the earliest possible: *(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West*.

All I had to do was setting this value to the correct one, and the problem was gone.